# c++ Karatsuba Multiplication using Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, karatsuba

So i've been trying to write out an algorithm for the Karatsuba Multiplication algorithm, and i've been attempting to use vectors as my data structure to handle the really long numbers which will be input...

My program can do smaller numbers fine, however it really struggles with larger numbers, and i get a core dump (Seg Fault). It also outputs strange results when the left hand side number is smaller than the right hand side.

Got any ideas? Heres the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

using namespace std;

vector<int> add(vector<int> lhs, vector<int> rhs) {
    int length = max(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
    int carry = 0;
    int sum_col;
    vector<int> result;

    while(lhs.size() < length) {
        lhs.insert(lhs.begin(), 0);
    }
    while(rhs.size() < length) {
        rhs.insert(rhs.begin(), 0);
    }

    for(int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum_col = lhs[i] + rhs[i] + carry;
        carry = sum_col/10;
        result.insert(result.begin(), (sum_col%10));
    }
    if(carry) {
        result.insert(result.begin(), carry);
    }
    int x = 0;
    while(result[x] == 0) {
        x++;
    }
    result.erase(result.begin(), result.begin()+x);
    return result;
}

vector<int> subtract(vector<int> lhs, vector<int> rhs) {
    int length = max(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
    int diff;
    vector<int> result;

    while(lhs.size() < length) {
        lhs.insert(lhs.begin(), 0);
    }
    while(rhs.size() < length) {
        rhs.insert(rhs.begin(), 0);
    }

    for(int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        diff = lhs[i] - rhs[i];
        if(diff >= 0) {
            result.insert(result.begin(), diff);
        } else {
            int j = i - 1;
            while(j >= 0) {
                lhs[j] = (lhs[j] - 1) % 10;
                if(lhs[j] != 9) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            result.insert(result.begin(), diff+10);
        }
    }
    int x = 0;
    while(result[x] == 0) {
        x++;
    }
    result.erase(result.begin(), result.begin()+x);
    return result;
}

vector<int> multiply(vector<int> lhs, vector<int> rhs) {
    int length = max(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
    vector<int> result;

    while(lhs.size() < length) {
        lhs.insert(lhs.begin(), 0);
    }
    while(rhs.size() < length) {
        rhs.insert(rhs.begin(), 0);
    }

    if(length == 1) {
        int res = lhs[0]*rhs[0];
        if(res >= 10) {
            result.push_back(res/10);
            result.push_back(res%10);
            return result;
        } else {
            result.push_back(res);
            return result;
        }
    }

    vector<int>::const_iterator first0 = lhs.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator last0 = lhs.begin() + (length/2);
    vector<int> lhs0(first0, last0);
    vector<int>::const_iterator first1 = lhs.begin() + (length/2);
    vector<int>::const_iterator last1 = lhs.begin() + ((length/2) + (length-length/2));
    vector<int> lhs1(first1, last1);
    vector<int>::const_iterator first2 = rhs.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator last2 = rhs.begin() + (length/2);
    vector<int> rhs0(first2, last2);
    vector<int>::const_iterator first3 = rhs.begin() + (length/2);
    vector<int>::const_iterator last3 = rhs.begin() + ((length/2) + (length-length/2));
    vector<int> rhs1(first3, last3);

    vector<int> p0 = multiply(lhs0, rhs0);
    vector<int> p1 = multiply(lhs1,rhs1);
    vector<int> p2 = multiply(add(lhs0,lhs1),add(rhs0,rhs1));
    vector<int> p3 = subtract(p2,add(p0,p1));

    for(int i = 0; i < 2*(length-length/2); i++) {
        p0.push_back(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < (length-length/2); i++) {
        p3.push_back(0);
    }

    result = add(add(p0,p1), p3);

    int x = 0;
    while(result[x] == 0) {
        x++;
    }
    result.erase(result.begin(), result.begin()+x);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> lhs;
    vector<int> rhs;
    vector<int> v;

    lhs.push_back(2);
    lhs.push_back(5);
    lhs.push_back(2);
    lhs.push_back(5);
    lhs.push_back(2);
    lhs.push_back(5);
    lhs.push_back(2);
    lhs.push_back(5);

    rhs.push_back(1);
    rhs.push_back(5);
    rhs.push_back(1);
    rhs.push_back(5);
    rhs.push_back(1);
    rhs.push_back(5);
    rhs.push_back(1);


    v = multiply(lhs, rhs);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `while(result[x] == 0) {x++;}` is definitely a problem (or, one of them) as you never check whether `x` is a valid index.

Comment: @ForceBru is there a more efficient way to erase all the 0's at the start of the number?

Comment: for (auto x : result)

Comment: or use this library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with `subtract`.  Since you don't have any way to represent a negative number, if `rhs` is greater than `lhs` your borrow logic will access before the beginning of of the data for `lhs`.

You can also march past the end of `result` when removing leading zeros if the result is 0.

Your borrow calculation is wrong, since `-1 % 10` will return -1, and not 9, if `lhs[j]` is 0.  A better way to calculate that is add 9 (one less than the value you're dividing by), `lhs[j] = (lhs[j] + 9) % 10;`.

In an unrelated note, you can simplify your range iteration calculations.  Since `last0` and `first1` have the same value, you can use `last0` for both, and `last1` is `lhs.end()`.  This simpifies `lhs1` to

```
vector<int> lhs1(last0, lhs.end());
```

and you can get rid of `first1` and `last1`.  Same goes for the `rhs` iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the tips mate, i really appreciate it